# Time Picker Value not Binding with View model In MAUI .net

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I'm Trying to Bind Time picker value with View model using Communitytook.mvvm. But my picker value is not getting it displays 12.00 AM continuously.

XAML file

```xml
<TimePicker 
    Time="{Binding Time1,Mode=TwoWay}"
    FontSize="Medium"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="time1"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Time1IsEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}"/>


<TimePicker
    Time="{Binding Time2,Mode=TwoWay}"
    FontSize="Medium"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="time2"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Time2IsEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Viewmodel.cs

```cs
namespace CRUDappMAUI.ViewModel
{
    public partial class AddLeaveViewModel : ObservableObject
    {   
        [ObservableProperty]
        DateTime _time1;

        [ObservableProperty]
        DateTime _time2;

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void SubmitClicked()
        {
            try
            {                
                Debug.WriteLine(_time1);
                Debug.WriteLine(_time2);               
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {             
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to get the time picker values to the View Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Time` property of `TimePicker` expects a `TimeSpan` typed value so you should change the type properties in your view model to `TimeSpan`. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/timepicker?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your `[ObservableProperty]` from `DateTime` to `TimeSpan`:

In your ViewModel.cs-file:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
TimeSpan mySelectedTime;
```

and in your *.xaml:

```xml
<TimePicker Time="{Binding MySelectedTime}"/>
```